# Shiny CSS Spinner

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I am currently using the package Shinycssloaders in order to add loader animations  to Shiny Outputs (e.g. plots, tables) in an automated fashion: https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders.

Just before my Shiny app completes loading the CSS spinner freezes for a few seconds and then renders the output. This seems to happen when there is a function call to shinyapp.js which takes about three seconds, after which the page is loaded. During those three seconds the spinner is frozen. Is there a way to remediate this issue? I understand that JavaScript runs on the UI thread, so it will block CSS-only spinners and I might need to work off the UI thread or split it up, yet I am not sure how to go about this.

Minimally Reproduceable Code (My app is considerably larger so the freeze duration is much longer):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- dashboardPage(
title = "Dashboard",
dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
dashboardSidebar(width = 205, 
sidebarMenu(id = "menutabs",
menuItem("Metrics", tabName = "metrics", icon = icon("bar-chart")))),
dashboardBody(
tabItems(
tabItem("metrics",
fluidRow(box(title = "Metrics", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary", collapsible = FALSE, withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("CTO"))))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$CTO <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(mtcars, options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE))})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: edit your question and add your code

Comment: Your example doesnt reproduce the problem, the example works fine for me

Comment: Yes the example does not fully reporduce the problem as it is mostly due to the size of my Shiny application. Since the Javascript takes a long time to load the spinner freezes. I cannot fully replicate the problem unless I include all ~4000 lines of code. I am just wondering if there is a way to thread the CSS spinners so they are not blocked by JS execution.